# Expo: how to add expo code to existing Android project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I have an Android app (standard java Android app) that allows the user creating its own 3D models. Now, I want to add a 3D viewer in this app so that the user can view his model and interact with it.

I plan to develop my 3D viewer with Expo.

Nevertheless, I wonder how I will be then able to integrate this 3D viewer in one of the activities of my Android java app.

Anybody could explain the process?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Expo by itself is only working for standalone apps. If you want to integrate it into an existing app, you have to use the "Bare" Workflow to integrate expo in an existing app. As all the tooling integration is a bit complicated I would suggest the following steps:

- generate a standard Expo-App
- use expo eject to convert it to the Bare Workflow
- Integrate your existing App into this created app.